# how can to find out which cumulative update is installed

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update

Guys ive inherited the admin of our company install of sharepoint.  I need to know which CU we have installed.  Can anyone tell me where i can find this information?

Comment: You can also check the SharePoint Detector to get the latest CU update installed [SHAREPOINT CUMULATIVE UPDATE DETECTOR](https://blog.devoworx.net/sharepoint-cumulative-update-detector/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224

To see which build your products are, go to Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > Check Product and patch installation status. (/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx)

To see which build your databases are, go to Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > Review database status (/_admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx)