# Restoring backup different server

Tags: backup, restore, solution-deployment

I have a requirement to move an entire site collection to a different server. The backup can be done through central admin.

The issue is that the new server, isn't really new. It has SharePoint 2010 installed with several old versions of all the custom webparts/features/pagelayaouts that are in the newer version. Essentially there are several out of date WSP package files that are currently deployed on the "new" server.

If when doing a restore, will I run into any issues, or will it be necessary for me to remove all the old files first.

Also, is a new site collection required to be created when performing the restore, or can I restore it to an existing site collection?

Also, do all OOB features in sharepoint need to be the same version on the restored server as the backuped server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Update your "new" server with the latest wsp-packages
- Create a new site collection, for testing purposes and restore your site collection there
- When you are done verifying everything is ok, backup the site collection you're restoring to. Everything will be overwritten when you restore.
- You can restore to both new or existing site collection. The effect will be the same.
- You should have the same CU status on both servers. It rules out any possible CU different errors.

Comment: How to check CU status on a server?

Comment: @TeddyRuxpin See answer on question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/43547/6382 :)